# BEA-101362 - [context] could not deserialize the scope scoped attribute with name: "name"

Tags: java, deserialization, weblogic-10.x

I've problem with attribute deserialization on WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.5.0. It raise error BEA-101362 which, I found, is commented as: http://iderror.com/errors/oracle/weblogic-103/wl103-http/bea-101362-context-could-not-deserialize-the-scope-scoped-attribute-with-name-name/ where is specified:

Classloader changed. When this happens, the old attributes will be deserialized using the new classloader. The classloader can change either as a result of dynamic reload of classes (controlled by weblogic.xml parameter “reload-check-secs” or upon across webapp dispatch (include/forward).

The first case "dynamic reload" is not my problem, this error happens each of time including immediately after servlet restart. Strange thing is that same code is working without problems on WepSphere app Server and even on older server version "WebLogic Server Version: 10.3.2.0".

Does anyone has similar experience with this deserialization problems?

Comment: Try [clearing the webapp cache](http://wlatricksntips.blogspot.com/2010/07/clearing-cache-for-weblogic-instance.html#.UPWCPycX9TI).  Weblogic would often resurrect an old copy of my applications and try to use it, causing some pretty bizarre scenarios.

Comment: we already cleared the cache without result ... I think that problem will be in different classloader behavior

Comment: for me clearing the cache did the job!